# How to preserve ampersand in URL's querystring when using RegisterClientScriptInclude?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, escaping

I have the need to add a javascript include to my ASP.NET page. The url of the javascript file has two key/value pairs in the query string. But the ampersand is being escaped and I don't want that.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("myKey",
    "https://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.2&s=1")
```

This results in the following HTML:

```
<script
    src="https://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.2&amp;s=1"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But what I really want is:

```
<script
    src="https://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.2&s=1"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into this in the past and never found a way around it.  I needed to create the URL server side and I don't like putting inline code in my aspx pages so I ended up using a `Literal` control and building the script tag and assigning it.

For your example:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Literal ID="ltScriptInclude" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Then in the `Page_Load`:

```
string url = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.2&s=1";
ltScriptInclude.Text = string.Format(
    "<script src=\"{0}\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>",
    url);
```

A complete recreation would be to also do a check for the registered key by wrapping the assignment in an `if` like:

```
if (IsStartupScriptRegistered("myKey"))
{
    // assign
    // set the key
}
```

But that is probably not needed since it is not being assigned anywhere else with the change of a `PostBack` double assigning it.

It's not the cleanest solution and it would have been nice if the `RegisterClientScriptInclude` had some type of param to tell it to not encode.  Unfortunately I don't think there is any way around it and the above isn't too bad.  Most includes for script files usually don't have the `&` so the vast majority would never run into this problem.

Comment: I make heavy use User Controls for dashboarding and so it is essencial I have the IsStartupScriptRegistered(string) functionality to avoid script duplicates, what's your recommended approach for this?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the encoded ampersand is valid HTML markup.  Your goal is an attempt to generate invalid markup.  Unencoded ampersands are not valid.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Mike, because an unescaped ampersand in an attribute is interpreted as the start of an entity reference as described in http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.2